# I need to match employee id on two different tabs and add the corresponding name to column

Tags: excel-formula

One tab has the user Id on it but I need to know who they are. On second tab I have the user id in column a and their name in column b. I need to add the name next to the user id on tab one. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: try Vlookup since you have the ID on both.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
    =INDEX(second!$B:$B,MATCH(first!A14,second!$A:$A,0))
```